# How to keep variable through an event?

Tags: c#

I have a method to populate a combobox with some strings. At the end of the method I assign to the `SelectedIndexChanged` event. Here's how that method looks

```
public ComboBox PopulateComboBox()
{
    Worksheet sheetWithTemplateNames = _iReader.GetWorksheetByName("Templates");
    int lastRowOfTemplates = _iReader.GetLastRow(sheetWithTemplateNames);
    var templateNames = _iHandler.GetTemplateNames(sheetWithTemplateNames, lastRowOfTemplates);
    foreach (var template in templateNames)
    {
        Box.Items.Add(template);
    }
    Box.SelectedIndexChanged += Box_SelectedIndexChanged;
    return Box;
}
```

and it works as I want to. My problem is that I need to use this `templateNames` list in the actual event and that's causing trouble. Here's how my event looks like now but ain't functioning.

```
private void Box_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox cmb = (ComboBox)sender;
    var chosenObject = cmb.SelectedIndex;
    MessageBox.Show(templateNames[chosenObject]);
}
```

but my list is now empty. It's instantiated in the constructor so I'd assume it'd keep it's state but that isn't the situation. Here's the top of the class

```
public class TemplateListCombobox
{
    public ComboBox Box { get; set; }
    private IDataReader _iReader;
    private IDataHandler _iHandler;
    private List<string> templateNames;

    public TemplateListCombobox()
    {
        Box = new ComboBox();
        _iReader = new DataReader();
        _iHandler = new DataHandler();
        templateNames = new List<string>();
    }
}
```

so how could I possibly keep the state of my list through the event?

UPDATE:

MY class that calls this:

```
public static class GroupBoxHolder
{
    private static GroupBox _thisGroupBox;

    public static GroupBox GetGroupBox()
    {
        PopulateGroupBox();
        return _thisGroupBox;
    }

    public static void PopulateGroupBox()
    {
        _thisGroupBox = new GroupBox();
        TemplateListCombobox combo = new TemplateListCombobox();
        ComboBox box = combo.GetComboBox();
        _thisGroupBox.Controls.Add(box);
        ConfigureGroupBox();
    }

    public static void ConfigureGroupBox()
    {
        _thisGroupBox.Location = new Point { X = 75, Y = 15  };
        _thisGroupBox.Height = 150;
        _thisGroupBox.Width = 400;
    }
}
```

and my updated class

```
public class TemplateListCombobox
{
    private ComboBox _box;
    private readonly IDataReader _iReader;
    private readonly IDataHandler _iHandler;
    private readonly Worksheet _sheetWithTemplateNames;

    public TemplateListCombobox()
    {
        _box = new ComboBox();
        _iReader = new DataReader();
        _iHandler = new DataHandler();
        _sheetWithTemplateNames = _iReader.GetWorksheetByName("Templates");
        PopulateComboBox();

    }
    public void PopulateComboBox()
    {
        int lastRowOfTemplates = _iReader.GetLastRow(_sheetWithTemplateNames);
        var templateNames = _iHandler.GetTemplateNames(_sheetWithTemplateNames, lastRowOfTemplates);
        foreach (var template in templateNames)
        {
            _box.Items.Add(template);

        }
        _box.SelectedIndexChanged += Box_SelectedIndexChanged;
    }

    public ComboBox GetComboBox()
    {
        return _box;
    }
    private void Box_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox cmb = (ComboBox)sender;
        var chosenObject = cmb.SelectedItem.ToString();
        var firstRowForTemplate = _iReader.GetFirstRowForTemplate(_sheetWithTemplateNames, chosenObject.ToString());
        var attributes =  _iReader.GetTemplateAttributes(_sheetWithTemplateNames, chosenObject, firstRowForTemplate);

    }
}
```

Comment: `var templateNames = _iHandler.GetTemplateNames .... ` should be changed to `templateNames = _iHandler.GetTemplateNames ...`

Comment: God that's embarrasing. Thanks a lot

Comment: You don't need `templateNames` and having it may lead to `IndexOutOfRangeException` exception if it gets out of sync with the combobox.

Answer (score 0):

## A. Two lists?

`var templateNames =` creates a new local variable.

Do you want to set a member field instead? If so, remove `var`.

## B. Read from comobox

Since the combo box contains the names read directly from it.

The flow of the code is something like the following:

```
var templateNames = _iHandler.GetTemplateNames(sheetWithTemplateNames, lastRowOfTemplates);
foreach (var template in templateNames)
{
   Box.Items.Add(template);
}

... time passes

var chosenObject = cmb.SelectedIndex;
MessageBox.Show(templateNames[chosenObject]);
```

The combobox contains all the information you need. (You could use `SelectedItem`).

---

#### Note on two sources.

Since you're not clearing the combobox's items in the populate method, if it was called twice the combobox would gain new elements. That's not great but more importantly `templateNames[chosenObject]` would not work anymore because the combobox and the list would be out of sync.

Comment: I have updated my OP with your update and a bit more information if you'd like to take another look. Thanks for your time already

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the `var templateNames` mistake that doesn't cause the problem, you don't call `PopulateComboBox` in the code you provide, so the list is empty...

I don't understand why this method returns the `Box` since there is no parameter and it is a member field that you access directly in the code.

You only need to assign the event in the constructor, not each time you call the populate method that you need to call somewhere.

You should improve your class design because there is several clumsiness. For example, what is `TemplateListCombobox` without parent and how do you intend to use it? How are initialized _iReader and _iHandler? Do you need to keep templateNames? And so on...

Comment: I've made Box private and kept the method.

The PopulateComboBox get's called from a GroupBox and added to that which gets added to my form. 

I am never instantiating the TemplateListComboBox without calling the PopulateComboBox right after so I'm not entirely sure how it makes a difference wether I do it in constructor or not? 

I do not need to keep templateNames since I'll save the one chosen template (haven't gotten that far yet). 

Basically each click I will populate my ComboBox with whatever templates they added. I've updated OP with the class calling the ComboBox.